# Close db2cmd prompt after command execution from a batch file

Tags: batch-file, db2

I am trying to close the db2cmd after executing a command. Goal is to get this file perfect before I schedule it with a task scheduler to run everyday at 2100 hours. The batch file starts execution of the command, the command gets executed but the prompt doesn't close.

I have been through the below links but no combination is working.
[How to close the command line window after running a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626178/how-to-close-command-line-window-after-a-batch-file-running)
[How to automatically close cmd window after batch file execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697739/how-to-automatically-close-cmd-window-after-batch-file-execution)

Here is my short script
    `start C:\"Program Files"\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2cmdadmin.exe "db2 -tvf D:\stats.sql > D:\stats.output"`

The command works but the prompt remains open after completion. I have tried doing -
 "&& exit 0",
"exit 0" in the next line,
"exit" in the next line,
"start db2cmdadmin "db2 -tvf D:\stats.sql > D:\stats.output""

But nothing closes the prompt. How can I correct this?

Comment: Why do you not put quotes around the _whole_ path? the syntax you are using (quotes _within_ the path) looks weird to me, I am even surprised that it works... you should use: `start "" "C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2cmdadmin.exe" ...` (so the entire path is quoted; the empty quoted string `""` is the window title; if omitted, `start` might get confused)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to add the command line switch `/c` to your command

```
start C:\"Program Files"\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2cmdadmin.exe /c "db2 -tvf D:\stats.sql > D:\stats.output"
```

as [explained in the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002036.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-2-6-35&lang=en).

Comment: Worked like a charm with just the addition of /c. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it usually works for me.  On at the end of `

```
start `C:\"Program Files"\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2cmdadmin.exe "db2 -tvf D:\stats.sql > D:\stats.output"
```

Put

```
goto eof
```

Then put a loop

```
:eof
```

and exit
So in total the code would be

```
@echo off
   start `C:\"Program Files"\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2cmdadmin.exe "db2 -tvf D:\stats.sql > D:\stats.output"
goto eof

:eof
exit
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even though I did not try this method, addition of /c did the trick and is much simpler than running a loop.