# How to automatically close cmd window after batch file execution for forever to run js background?

Tags: node.js, express, forever

I have a batch file with only one line code to run:

```
start forever start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www
```

This line is used to run "forever" (https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) ,and it works ,but get the cmd window remained。I refered to these tow threads（[How to automatically close cmd window after batch file execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697739/how-to-automatically-close-cmd-window-after-batch-file-execution), 
     [Close db2cmd prompt after command execution from a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33576184/close-db2cmd-prompt-after-command-execution-from-a-batch-file)） but failed , and I tried several formats and got no success.The codes i tried is as below:

```
 start forever /c  start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www rem cann't run
start forever /c "start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www" rem cann't run
cmd /c start forever start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www rem run w/windows remained
start "" "forever" start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www rem run w/windows remained
start "" "forever" start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www /c rem run w/windows remained
start /c "" "forever" start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www rem run w/o result no windows remained
start "" /c forever start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www rem run w/o result no windows remainstart "" ""forever" start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www" /c rem cann't run
start "" forever start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www /c rem run w/windows remained
start "" "forever" /c start "-a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log" www rem os can't find the path.
start "" "forever" start -a -l forever.log -o out.log -e err.log www /c rem run w/windows remained
```

Can somebody give some advise?tks.