# start a simple batch file to run a python script then terminate the cmd window

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a simple batch file which has:

```
python mySript.py
```

I save the file as `.bat`, I run it, everything is fine except the cmd window stays. I tried many solutions, but nothing worked.

The python script is a tkinter app, and I want to get the ***app window only*** when I run the batch file, not the cmd window (should close automtically after running the batch)

Btw, I tried also `START \b`, but that didn't help.

Comment: Don't know if it helps, but have a look here for possible solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626178/how-to-close-the-command-line-window-after-running-a-batch-file

Comment: I already tried this one, but didn't help also. But thanks for the comment anyway

Comment: [exit](https://ss64.com/nt/exit.html)?

Comment: exit doesn't help, because it stucks at the line `python mySript.py`, it waits for it to finish

Comment: `start "" pythonw mySript.py`

Comment: ´start "" pythonw mySript.py´ that closes yes the cmd win, but brings up the powershell win :)

Comment: Either your script should be called `myScript.pyw` or you should use `pythonw` to run it since it is a windows app.. Then you can use `start` to start it in its own process and your batch file will terminate before the script does.

Comment: where does powershell come from? are you calling powershell inside of the python file? If so, that means you use a batch file, to call a python script, that calls powershell??

Comment: additionally, the attempt to run `start \b` will not work as it expects a forward slash to define the switch. `start /b`

Answer (score 3):

When reading the help, via `cmd.exe` for `start /?` you will see the first line states:

> Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

So all you need to do is:

```
start "" python mySript.py
```

Which will launch the python script and directly exit the batch file, if launched by double click.

Comment: Wow, this one worked for me. Thought I'd tried everything!